# Using Ubuntu as second monitor

Tags: dual-boot, monitor

I have an HP laptop that is dual-booted windows with Ubuntu along. I want to use windows on my laptop and ubuntu on the monitor such that both can run side by side. Is it possible??

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: If you run one of those operating systems in a virtual machine, then yes. Otherwise, you cannot have a single computer running two operating systems (as you suggest) simultaneously.

Comment: Thought of it, Thanks a lot for clarifying!

Comment: In addition, if you run Win 10 you can use the recent feature WSL in order to use ubuntu terminal on Windows 10.